# render 'form' not showing columns added using a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Initially I ran `rails g scaffold Post title:string content:text` and after migrating everything worked fine.

However, later on I decided to add a tags column, so I did `rails g migration AddTagsToPosts tags:string` and `rake db:migrate`.

Although the output from those commands seemed normal, the /posts/new page still only shows the initial two fields, title and content. The same goes for /posts/x/show and /posts/x/edit.
The view file itself only contains `render 'form'`, so apparently I missed something here?

Do I have to run any additional commands to add the new fields to the forms?

Just starting to get into Rails, and this particular issue is pretty hard to google so I figured I'd ask the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the migration doesn't change the views that were creating by generating the scaffold. So you either need to re-run the generation for the scaffold, or just manually edit the _form file to add the new columns.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure what to look for and somehow didn't notice that file.

Answer (score 2):

Form partial isn't updated automatically after migration. You should manually add new fields to _form.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your rails server and rails console. Worked for me.